# Можно ли определить настоящий IP?

Tags: ip, прокси

Если используется прокси прописанное в браузере к примеру Firefox, и на 2ip.ru пишет что прокс не используется, можно ли как то определить настоящий IP адрес пользователя?

Comment: Никак. Реальный адрес пользователя — 192.168.0.4 в своей домашней сети, что это вам даст?

Comment: VladD Это как раз таки частный адрес, а не реальный. А вопрос автора   про прокси, а не про адрес на интерфейсе компьютера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суть прокси - воспроизводить запрос от оригинального пользователя, но со своего адреса.

Если прокси не настроен добавлять заголовок [X-Forwarded-For](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) - то нет, обнаружить его никак нельзя. Потому что запрос от него выглядит точно так же, как обычный запрос от пользователя, если бы у того был тот внешний ip-адрес, который присвоен прокси.

Comment: а как узнать настроен или нет?

Comment: @emtecif со стороны сервера проверить наличие заголовка. 2ip.ru, судя по всему, проверяет - и заголовка нет.